Wordpress shortcode with JS
I am working on a wordpress project and I'm completely stuck on something ... I have to put somewhere near the post (in a post grid page) the reading time of them. So I got to test laking a js script that take the url (href found on a element) and a function in the function.php file of my theme that take the url of a post and return the calculated reading time... Though, it work when I put manually the shortcode, but not when I'm using JS.
(BTW, I'm using elmentor as well ...)
JS script (html block):
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    let childDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.void-row > *');
    childDivs.forEach(child =>{
        let links = child.querySelectorAll('a');
        let postUrl = links[0].href;
        let short = `[get_post_reading_time url=${postUrl}]`;
        links[4].textContent = short;
    });
});
</script>

Php Function (function.php):
function get_post_reading_time($att = '', $content = null){
    $url = $att['url'];
    $post_id = url_to_postid($url);
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $word_count = str_word_count(strip_tags($content));
    return ceil($word_count / 200);
}

add_shortcode('get_post_reading_time', 'get_post_reading_time');

Could someone help me understand and/or find another way to do that? Thanks in advance.
(Maybe it's because function.php replace the shortcode in the JS script before it is inside the textContent of the links[4] ?)

The shortcode is interpreted and rendered by PHP (which means translated into HTML and/or JS code), it is not possible to add it with JS when the page is already rendered

Assuming this is saved as meta data for each post. It should be fairly easy to just inject that for the output in a similar manner using just PHP. Would just need to check the query or I think Elementor Pro (assuming you have it or one of the free plugins that lets you use templates) add it directly through there if it is meta data.

I would use AJAX to easier fetch data, here's how function.php should look:
function record_reading_time() {
    if (isset($_POST['url'], $_POST['time_spent'])) {
        $url = $_POST['url'];
        $time_spent = intval($_POST['time_spent']); // Convert to integer
        $post_id = url_to_postid($url);

        // Here you can update a post meta or perform any other action
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'user_time_spent', $time_spent);

        echo 'Time successfully recorded';
        wp_die(); // Important for proper AJAX response termination
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_record_reading_time', 'record_reading_time');
add_action('wp_ajax_record_reading_time', 'record_reading_time');

then, for the frontend javascript I would use a function like this:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
let startTime = Date.now();
    function sendTimeOnPage() {
        let endTime = Date.now();
        let timeSpent = endTime - startTime; // Time in milliseconds
        let postUrl = window.location.href;

        // Send the time spent back to the server using AJAX
        fetch(ajaxurl, {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            }),
            body: `action=record_reading_time&url=${encodeURIComponent(postUrl)}&time_spent=${timeSpent}`
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => console.log('Success:', data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', sendTimeOnPage);
});


be sure to replace ajaxurl with the URL where AJAX requests should be sent.

Now, this is what i know about what you are asking about, but im not that expert on Workdpress, soo make sure your JavaScript is enqueued properly in WordPress, and adapt if you have more custom hacks ;)
